# What do native English speakers mean by "Russian"?

Tags: meaning, translation, russian

When you're translating a text containing the word *Russian* from English to Russian, you must be aware of the context, because it can mean "a citizen of Russia, regardless of ethnicity" (*россиянин*), or "an ethnic Russian, not necessarily a citizen of Russia" (*русский*), or both, in which case there is no single word for it in Russian.

**What do native speakers of English usually mean when they use the word *Russian* (when referring to a person or people)?**

As I understand it, native English speakers are not acutely aware of the distinction between the two meanings, but it's very important in Russia.

Comment: ***Russian***: ***1***. adjective
Russian means belonging or relating to Russia, or to its people, language, or culture.
*...the Russian parliament.* 
***2***. countable noun
A Russian is a person who comes from Russia.
*Three-quarters of Russians live in cities.* 
***3***. uncountable noun
Russian is the language spoken in Russia, and other countries such as Belarus, Kazakhstan, and Kyrgystan. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/russian

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What we mean when we use the word "Russian" depends on the context. You ask about the noun use, but appear to overlook the adjective. Generally, "a Russian" is probably a citizen of the Russian Federation, regardless of ethnic classification. Something that is "Russian" (adjective) is something from that country. Russian (noun, no article) is the language.

Comment: Surely it depends on the context - though I suppose that in most contexts there is no need to make a distinction between the two.

Comment: This may end up being an opinion question. How many native English speakers are even aware that the concept of "ethnic Russian" exists?

Comment: @shoover, in a sense, what you're talking about is at the heart of the question.

Comment: This is like an Eskimo asking what do native speakers of English usually mean when they use the word *snow*.

Comment: Why is it important in Russia to distinguish between the two concepts ( citizen vs ethnic)?

Comment: @user240918, well, I suppose it's useful to make this distinction when 2/3 of the Russian Federation are ethnic Russians, and the rest are not. Also, it is an important distinction because ethnic and non-ethnic citizens of Russia are (usually) people who behave quite differently, though this difference is slowly dissapearing as a result of assimilation.

Comment: I see, but that is a nuance that is typical of the Russian culture. Foreigners, not only English people would have to refer to citizen which are also ethic Russian and those who are not.

Comment: I am a native English speaker, and thanks to Martin Cruz Smith's Arkady Renko novels, I know that there are different ethic groups in Russia. Kalmyk, Uzbek, Tatar, Russian, they are all "Russian".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this question is very similar to ‘what’s the difference between being English or being from the UK?’, I think that there is scant awareness of the difference between ‘Russian’ (from the country) and ‘Russian’ (ethnically) in the UK.

I think you are correct - that there is not an acute awareness of this.

In fact I think there is almost no awareness of it. I myself had never heard of it, it never crossed my mind. Thanks for pointing it out.

So I think, in translating, you could say ‘Russian citizens’ or ‘ethnic Russians’. Which would at least... begin the process of letting us know that there is a difference.

When native English speakers refer to ‘Russians’ they typically mean ‘anyone from Russia’. Without knowing there is a distinction.

“How can the confessor teach/ those who are lost and sick at heart,/ when he himself, among the sinners,/ is worst, and most forsaken?/ It is only a game we play/ with other people's sins./ Besides, everyone knows/ that everyone lies confessing.” 
― Yevgeny Yevtushenko, Stolen Apples

Comment: The person you quoted is an ethnic Ukranian... the irony.

Comment: The demonstration... of